# Getting html data in nodejs (electron gui)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, user-interface, electron

so im making a gui for a application and i was wondering if its possible to get a html form submission using nodejs? ive seen people do funky ways like sending it over servers but the real thing is its a gui and not a http server. is there anyway i could get data from html in node js. Example: Say i submitted "hello world" onto my html form. How would i be able to get that string in nodejs. i tried a lot of things such as inline javascript but thats funky because i need nodejs to use the string in a txt file.

Answer (score 2):

The common solution for this is to use the `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` modules in electron. `ipcMain` is basically the reciever for information in the electron main process (i.e., your GUI backend) and `ipcRenderer` is the sender and reciever for information in the electron renderer process/your GUI front end.

What you can do is listen for an event, like a button click for example, then get the html input value and send this data to your electron main process, then you can do whatever you want with this data in the electron backend.

Here's a pretty basic example

Let's say this is your HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter some data" id="input_data" />
<button onclick="sendToBackend()">Send</button>
<script src="./main.js"></script>
```

And let's say this is `main.js`:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

function sendToBackend() {
   ipcRenderer.send("newData", {value: document.getElementById("input_data").value});
}
```

Now in your electron js file, let's say you had something like this:

```
... other electron logic above
const { ipcMain } = require("electron");

ipcMain.on("newData", (event, data) => {
   console.log(data.value); // Will output whatever was inside input element in HTML
});
```

Also, you may need to enable `nodeIntegration` on your browser window and disbale `contextIsolation`.

Answer (score 0):

`ipcRenderer` and `ipcMain` can be used to communicate between main and renderer processes. The HTML form you want to extract data from is the renderer process.

You can use a `preload` script for the renderer processes that create a contextBridge (a safe way to create APIs that "bridges" between the main and renderer processes) and use `ipcRenderer` to send the data from the renderer process upon events that you can listen for in the script linked to HTML. [Here](https://gist.github.com/malept/3a8fcdc000fbd803d9a3d2b9f6944612) is a gist that shows in detail how you can send data from forms to the main process as explained above.